# nativescript-geolocation crash on geolocation.enableLocationRequest()

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I use **Android 10.0 (Pixel 3a) on an emulator** and **nativescript-vue** as my stack.

Whenever I call `geolocation.enableLocationRequest()` either on `mounted()` or on button click, the app crash.

It works fine on iOS though.

Any ideas?

#### Update 1 - More Info

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="10003" android:versionName="0.0.3">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
    <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
                  android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                  android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme"
        >
            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is what I do on button click:

```
try {
            let that = this;
    geolocation.isEnabled().then(function (isEnabled) {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            geolocation.enableLocationRequest().then(function () {
                this.watchIds.push(geolocation.watchLocation(
                    function (loc) {
                        if (loc) {
                            console.log("Location service: " + loc.timestamp)
                            that.$store.dispatch('usersStore/editUserGeo', {lat: loc.latitude, lng: loc.longitude})
                            that.locations.push(loc);
                        }
                    },
                    function (e) {
                        console.log("Error: " + e.message);
                    },
                    {
                        iosAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: true,
                        desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high,
                    }));
            }, function (e) {
                console.log("Error: " + (e.message || e));
            });
        }
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + (e.message || e));
    });
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("Error: " + ex.message);
    }
```

Device logs just around the crash occurrence:
https://pastebin.com/VuK5nEBi

Comment: Please add more details, at least a complete crash log would be better.

Comment: @Manoj , I've added more info. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cannot enable the location service. Error:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbck;

It's a known issue and the solution is already given in the plugin [docs](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/README.md#version-conflicts--google-play-services).

> In order to fix this you might pin the version number in your
>   app/App_Resources/Android/before-plugins.gradle file (if the file does
>   not exist, just create it):

```
android {  
  // other stuff here

  project.ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG Bro, saving lives once again. 
Thanks!